# How to add element to array nested in another array in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have another question about mongoose. This time I want to update array element inside other array in my document. It's strucuture looks like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5702e0c732faf57c7bb9ebe9"),
    "email" : "john@doe.me",
    "projects" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "inbox",
            "title" : "Inbox",
            "tasks" : [ 
                {
                    "id" : "1",
                    "text" : "First task",
                    "labels" : [ 
                        "home", 
                        "phone"
                    ],
                    "dueDate" : "2016-03-18T11:10:00",
                    "created" : "2016-03-10T10:10:00",
                    "completed" : false
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "work",
            "title" : "Work",
            "tasks" : [ 
                {
                    "id" : "4",
                    "text" : "Fourth",
                    "labels" : [ 
                        "home", 
                        "phone"
                    ],
                    "dueDate" : "2016-03-18T11:10:00",
                    "created" : "2016-03-10T10:10:00",
                    "completed" : false
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to find document by `_id`, select project by `name` and then add new task inside `tasks` array. What is the best way to do this? For now I tried to use `findOne` to see if I'm querying right place

```
User.findOne(
  { _id: Mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId), 'projects.name': data.project },
  (err, data) => {
    if (err) { throw err; }

    console.log(data);
  }
);
```

But it returns all projects in array and I don't know how to select project I'm looking for and add element to `tasks` array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
User.update({_id:ObjectId(userId),'projects.name': data.project},{$push:{'projects.$.tasks':{yourTaskObject}}})
```

$ in update works as positional operator which fetches the position of the parent array

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution

```
User.update(
  { _id: Mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId), 'projects.name': data.project },
  { $push: { 'projects.$.tasks': data.task } },
  (err, data) => {
    if (err) { throw err; }

    return reply('success');
  }
);
```